# NLP-Name Entity Recognition : How to map different naming of the entity to the same entity? AMC vs AMC Entertainment vs AMC Theatres

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am doing a named entity recognition task where I am counting how many times a certain entity was mentioned in a document.

What I found is the different naming convention of the same entity has been counted separately.
For example AMC, AMC Entertainment, AMC theatres.
How can I know they are all referring to the same entity and count it 3 times, instead of counting 1 time for each?

Currently using Spacy, open to other python solutions.
https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve is called entity linking. Entity linking resolves a textual entity to a unique identifier which in your case linking several entities e.g. AMC, AMC Entertainment, AMC theatres to a unique entity. More information [here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#entity-linking) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking).